# How to overwrite files added using SparkContext.addFile?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use sc.addFile to add a file to all worker nodes. However, I found it could not overwrite the same file. Is there any way to overwrite a file through sc.addFile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is configured with [`spark.files.overwrite`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> Whether to overwrite files added through SparkContext.addFile() when the target file exists and its contents do not match those of the source.

So just set it to `true` in your config

```
spark.files.overwrite   true
```

or session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.conf("spark.files.overwrite", "true").getOrCreate()
sc  = spark.sparkContext
```

or `SparkConf`

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.files.overwrite", "true")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: After setting the configuration to true it doesn't work for me. I add the file the first time using `addFile`, then I update the content of the file and call the `addFile` again, but it doesn't update the file. What am I missing?

Comment: This is misleading. According to document, "Users can not overwrite the files added by SparkContext.addFile or SparkContext.addJar before even if this option is set true."

Answer (score 0):

just minor change on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3269809/alper-t-turker). I need to use config instead of conf in builder otherwise I will get "builder has no conf " error

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.files.overwrite", "true").getOrCreate()
```